# How to mock method to return any Type that extends common interface but not concrete one in Mockito Framework

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, stub

I wonna stub a method of a class. I would like to that stubbed method to return any type that implements common interface but not the concrete one.

For example:

```
public interface CommonType() {}
public class SubTypeOne implements CommonType {}
public class SubTypeTwo implements CommonType {}
public class SubTypeThree implements CommonType {}
public class SubTypeToNotReturn implements CommonType {}
```

`when(object.methodToStub()).thenReturn( )`

What should I put into `thenReturn()` brackets when I wonna mock to return any class of:

`CommonType`,`SubTypeOne`,`SubTypeTwo`,`SubTypeThree`

but not the `SubTypeToNotReturn`

I've tried already:

`when(object.methodToStub()).thenReturn(not(new SubTypeToNotReturn()))`

but it doesnt work. I am getting an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: No matchers found for Not(?).
```

Comment: For one test condition, you would need only one output to be returned. what are going to achieve with your desired behavior ?

Comment: So You propose to return concrete type, f.e.: `SubTypeThree`? What I am trying to achieve is a hight quality test units.